# Artifactory Tomcat password

Tags: java, tomcat, artifactory

I have installed artifactory on my Ubuntu m/c following the instruction given in 
http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS
I have tried to install the artifactory as the service in my system.
for that I ran below command
$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/bin/installService.sh
it was installed perfectly onto my system,but when i tried to restart artifactory with following command it is asking for the password

service artifactory start | stop

I dont remember setting any password. So could any one please help me with which password it is asking. And please let me know if reinstalling is a good option for this

Answer (score 1):

The default password is "password".

More on user management and resetting the password here:
http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Users

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute "service artifactory start" with sudo privileges: `sudo service artifactory start`